# How to add Swing component to SWT?

Tags: java, swing, swt, eclipse-rcp

I want to add a Swing component (`JTree`) to my code which employs SWT.
Is there any way by which we can accomplish this?
I know that we have `TreeViewer` component in SWT/Jface, but i have got an already developed Jtree implemenatation and would like to add that, instead of rewriting using TreeViewer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [SWT/AWT Bridge](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Swing-SWT-Integration/index.html).

```
Composite composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.EMBEDDED | SWT.NO_BACKGROUND);
Frame frame = SWT_AWT.new_Frame(composite);
```

The `SWT_AWT.newFrame(Compisite)` method will return a `java.awt.Frame`. Since a `Frame` is a `Container` you can add any `Component`. Thus also a swing component.

Comment: +1, that works like a charm. Though there is one issue with the alignment, not able to position the added Jpanel. I have updated the question with the same.

Comment: the issue was with the parent composite. Marked the question as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The http://wiki.eclipse.org/Albireo_Project might help:

"The Albireo project builds on the SWT_AWT bridge to provide more complete Swing/SWT integration, resulting in a better "out-of-the-box" experience and more credibility for the entire notion of Swing/SWT integration."

Extend the `SwingControl` and implement `createSwingComponent()` and `getLayoutAncestor()`. http://eclipsesrc.appspot.com/jsrcs/org.eclipse.albireo/org.eclipse.albireo.core/src/org/eclipse/albireo/core/SwingControl.java.html