# Swing/Prefuse or SWT for eclipse plugin development

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, plugins, swt

I have existing java application where GUI had mainly built using Swing and prefuse API (http://prefuse.org/). 
I want to develop eclipse plugin for this application. I have read in vogella tutorial that SWT is prefer to use for plugin development.

My problem is that if I should use SWT, then how can I convert each swing and prefuse API component to SWT?

PS: If I use existing GUI in my eclipse plugin project, then when I run the plugin as "Eclipse Application", it display GUI outside eclipse which I am not sure is correct behaviour for plugin development.

Comment: Added. I cannot use more than 5 tags.

Comment: You may be able to use the `SWT_AWT` class to run the Swing code from SWT, example [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/EmbededSwingAWTcomponentstoSWT.htm)

Answer (score 0):

The http://wiki.eclipse.org/Albireo_Project might help:

"The Albireo project builds on the SWT_AWT bridge to provide more complete Swing/SWT integration, resulting in a better "out-of-the-box" experience and more credibility for the entire notion of Swing/SWT integration."

Extend the `SwingControl` and implement `createSwingComponent()` and `getLayoutAncestor()`.
http://eclipsesrc.appspot.com/jsrcs/org.eclipse.albireo/org.eclipse.albireo.core/src/org/eclipse/albireo/core/SwingControl.java.html

Comment: I don't understant what is the relation of your answer with the actual question? Looks like your answer is just spam.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20905989/how-to-add-swing-component-to-swt/22043075#22043075

Comment: The Albireo project extends the SWT_AWT bridge, for cleaner embedding.
If you want to run swing in an Eclipse/SWT environment, this might be the way to go. At least in our application it works fine embedding a jgraph (swing) editor.

Comment: I copy pasted the post because, I saw your question in the "Related" and thought it might be of interest.